# Sharing Links On Non-Public Beta Sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, usability

I get the following message while trying to share a question from a non-public beta site on Facebook:

```
Log In - Code Golf - Stack Exchange
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2/6
Warning: this site is currently in private beta for 6 more days. Unless you committed to its Area 51 site proposal, you won’t be able to log in!
```

While I am fully aware why this happens, my question is, while sites are non-public should the share links be included at the bottom of a question.

Because they are just about useless if the site is non-public, and a little confusing if you are not familiar with how authentication and the web works.

Answer (score 2):

Private betas no longer have a `share` link.

This has already been rolled out to the entire network.

Comment: Is this new, fixed now due to this report, or was it already in place for unknown amount of time? :)

Comment: Well, they do appear to have the link (handy if you're sharing something in chat / etc with others that _do_ have access) - but the social icons are not present on private betas.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nick Craver was looking through the bug lists and fixed it. I am just reporting it.