# Do not offer to *Share a link* on private beta

Tags: bug, private-beta, share-this

On a private beta I'm currently on, I see the notice below an unanswered question:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook

That suggestion should not be there, because only members can see questions.

(Note that this is different from *[Sharing Links On Non-Public Beta Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76768/172266)*.  The "normal" share-link is not available on private betas, but the *Know someone?* one still is)

Comment: IIRC private betas are only truly private for a short time, after that anyone can join if they know where to look. There's this link from a few years ago, but I've seen it mentioned [reasonably recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54536/146015) (possibly that it still said "private" beta even though the public could join).

Answer (score 5):

I assume that's by design to some extent. These private betas have opportunities to invite experts who didn't sign up for the beta.

If you know someone who can answer a question on a private beta *we want them there*. We shouldn't block people from inviting potential experts into a private community, those are the people we want in that community from day one.

Comment: But the link won't work for them unless I /also/ send them a private beta invite link, I think.

Comment: Perhaps there should be the option to invite them to the private beta instead of the normal link.

Comment: Agreed this is by design. Private betas aren't quite private. It does prevent the content from being viewed without an account, but anyone can sign up if they want. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212235/why-am-i-allowed-to-sign-up-on-a-private-beta-site-i-never-commited-to/212239#212239)

Comment: @gerrit not necessarily, its trivial to enter a private beta without an invite now. Though if you know someone who should be answering *why haven't you already sent them the link* :)

Comment: @waxeagle Oh, that's new for me.  Well, one answer is that I can put a 'share' link in a public place, whereas 'private beta invites' are to individuals.