# Should the "Share" link be returned to private betas to help facilitate internal discussion?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, private-beta

Should the "Share" link be re-added to posts in private beta? I've seen [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76768/sharing-links-on-non-public-beta-sites) where it was feature-requested to *remove* the link, because the site was, well, private. So the link won't just work for non-registered users, I've got that. But it would be so useful internally.

[Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions) has been up for just about an hour, and already I've wanted to share multiple answers (mostly on meta). When you think about it, this functionality is pretty crucial to internal discussion. I had to figure out how to invent the link to a meta answer when I was writing a new meta question. A Share link would be *so* much easier. What if I want to discuss a particular main-site answer on meta? Do I have to link to the question and name the user whose answer I'm discussing? Links make much more sense.

Comment: You can't use the share link directly, you have to direct any possible users to the A51 proposal, else they won't be able to log in and create an account.

Comment: @MadScientist Fair enough, but I still think it's useful for internal use... What if I want to ask a meta question about a specific answer? I can link to the question, but a share link on the answer would be so much easier...

Comment: I could well be wrong, but isn't any beta only truly private for the first week or two, after that they are still marked as private but it's possible for new non-followers to sign up directly? I'm sure I saw this mentioned somewhere when someone commented that a non follower had been able to directly sign up on a private beta.

Comment: @slugster Any private beta now allows folks to sign up through Area 51 (or via an email invitation from an existing user). After a week or two, the site flips to  public beta and then anyone can sign up directly from the site itself.

Comment: "I had to figure out how to invent the link to a meta answer when I was writing a new meta question." Seems perfect for a site on puzzling :-) More seriously: very good proposal! I found the lack of an easy way to link also inconvenient when matheductaors.SE was in private beta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Update: The 'share' link is now included in all private betas.*

---

Yes. I've already written this up internally.

Since the private betas are [no longer strictly "members only"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212239/98786), the reason for [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76768/98786) is not as prevalent as it once was. If someone stumbles across one of these links somewhere on the Internet, they can now find their way into the site by simply signing up.

I believe that encouraging *easy* collaboration during a private beta is more important than trying to protect these "private beta" links from getting out in the wild. I can't make any promises (not my decision), but I am going to re-raise this issue to see if we can get that changed.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I look forward to hearing how this turns out :)

Comment: Boom!! I *knew* I'd seen this mentioned somewhere.